# Why IE10 shows style differently than other browsers

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I have the following HTML:

```
<td class="tdGo" style="background-color: #0000FF;">
     <img src="theImages/search_go.png" id="imgGo" class="imgGo" />
</td>
```

CSS:

```
td.tdGo {
    padding-right: 24px;
    text-align: right;
}
.imgGo {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('.imgGo').each(function() {
    var std = $(this).attr("src");
    var hover = std.replace("theImages/search_go.png", "theImages/search_go_rollover.png");
    $(this)
        .clone()
        .insertAfter(this)
        .attr('src',hover)
        .removeClass('imgGo')
        .siblings()
        .css({position:'absolute'});
    $(this)
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 0);
        })
        .mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
        });
});
```

IE10:

[image]

IE8:

[image]

FF/Chrome:

[image]

For some reason in IE10 the images appear in two different place and I can't seem to figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

This is what the DEV tool is showing:

[image]

Comment: Have you examined the rendered CSS in your browser tools?

Comment: I updated my question with the dev tool screenshot.

Comment: That's a pretty funky way to do a rollover. The issue must be caused by your use of `clone()`.

Comment: Why are you not just doing this in CSS? There is no need to use JavaScript to do a rollover.

Comment: I am looking to support in all browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE10 is the only one rendering this correctly: An element with `position:absolute` is out of the flow, and therefore does not respond to `text-align:right` when determining its position.

Consider using this CSS:

```
td.tdGo {
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:24px;
    position:relative;
}
.imgGoRollover {
    position:absolute;
    right:24px;
}
```

Also, be aware that your jQuery is creating elements with duplicate IDs - make sure you remove the ID attribute from the cloned element.

Comment: I wouldn't say that the other browsers are wrong o_0, as it isn't exactly respecting the text-align right, but more like it remembers where it was before and presets the `top` and `left` values instead of just being 0. Not saying this is the correct way of doing it, but it's simple to fix by specifying the position manually (which you should anyway, assuming the default value of something is dangerous in the first place)

Comment: I used the `:after` to ensure the transition is working correctly.